# Remove padding on object-fit: contain (Image scaling layour)

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I will describe the problem in short (I used different colors for divs):

This is my current situation of my layout:

[Current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJNxN.png)

And when I resize vertically the browser windows happens this:

[Current situation resized vertically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU3NX.png)

My html code is:

```
  <div class="wrap-container">         <!-- Yellow container-->
    <div class="wrap">                 <!-- Grey container-->
      <div class="image">              <!-- Aqua container-->
        <img src="images/me.png"/>     <!-- Red container-->
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

And my CSS is:

```
.wrap-container{
  background-color: yellow;
}

.wrap{
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.image-container{
  height: 100%;
  background: aqua;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;

  img{
    height: 80%;
    object-fit: contain;
    object-position: left;
    background: red;
    max-width: 368px; /* the original width of the image */
    max-height: 332px; /* the original height of the image */
 }
}
```

I want that aqua box scales with the image (so the red should never be seen), like this image below:

[Desired final layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUJ24.png)

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your provided code does not recreate your shown conditions, but the easiest way to achieve what you want is to change `object-fit: contain;` to `object-fit: cover;`

I've tried my best to recreate your conditions and made a few edits to simplify the controls.

The `justify: flex-end` on the image class has no benefit, and the height % values were working against you, so I've exchanged it for padding.

```css
.wrap-container {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 450px;
}

.image {
  background: aqua;
  padding-top: 10%;
  Width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

img {
  background: red;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-container">
  <!-- Yellow container-->
  <div class="wrap">
    <!-- Grey container-->
    <div class="image">
      <!-- Aqua container-->
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" />
      <!-- Red container-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```